# asyn issues in react and jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm new to React and javascript. In the page, there are tabs, each responsible for one view (the click event handler handles it) and the content pulled from APIs by using jquery ajax

```
class Process extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        proc: {},
        procRel: {},
        tabSegment: "#execution-details"
    }
    this.handleSwitchTab = this.handleSwitchTab.bind(this)
}

handleSwitchTab(e) {
    let segment = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("href")
    if (segment === "#relationship") {
        $.post({
            // hidden
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({
                    procRel: data,
                })
            }.bind(this),
        })
    }
    this.setState({
        tabSegment: segment
    })
}
componentDidMount() {
    document.title = title
    $.post({
        // hidden
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            this.setState({
                proc: data,
            })
        }.bind(this),
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="process-wrapper">
            <header className="process-header">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#execution-details" onClick={this.handleSwitchTab}><img src={ProcessTabLogo}
                                                                                         alt=""/><span>Execution</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#relationship" onClick={this.handleSwitchTab}><img src={RelationshipTabLogo}
                                                                                    alt=""/><span>Relationship</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </header>
            <div className="process-content">
                {this.state.tabSegment === "#execution-details" && <ProcessExecution proc={this.state.proc}/>}
                {this.state.tabSegment === "#relationship" && <ProcessRel procRel={this.state.procRel}/>}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And the problems in ProcessRel component come when accessing attributes of this.props.procRel

```
class ProcessRel extends React.Component {
render() {
    let procTree = this.props.procRel
    console.log(procTree.Nodes)
    // hidden
}
```

The data of procRel is kind of [view procRel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szjh4.png)

It shown the error: TypeError: e.Nodes is undefined with kind of unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.production.min.js:19. What am I missing something ? Thanks and the complete page is  [here](https://github.com/tiencong283/gosysmon/blob/master/client/src/components/Process/Process.js#L52)

Comment: What (*component*) is passing `procRel` prop to `ProcessRel`? What is the value when it is passed?

Comment: Using jQuery in a React app is considered an issue.

Comment: The component passing to procRel you can see the link above for more clearance. The procRel is json object with one of the keys named Nodes which is an array in format: [[int, int], [int, int], ...]

Comment: why does React still recommend it in faq-ajax ?

Comment: AJAX isn't jquery. AJAX is simply **A**synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **X**ML. But yes, as a generality, don't mix in jquery with react, though here it is likely *ok* since it is used to make an asynchronous request versus direct DOM manipulation. What is the value of `this.state.procRel` when it is passed as a prop in that firstsnippet? Can you update your question to include all relevant code? [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `ProcessRel` will render before the ajax request returns its data, so in the parent component with the tabs is `this.state.procRel` undefined at the start?

Comment: Yes. I guessed that ProcessRel rendered before the ajax request completed

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

can you check your response data, maybe something went wrong with this?
also, you have to use [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to fetch any response from the server.